# Properties of lists with arbitrary lengths and alphabet size

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am having trouble understanding a problem of applying the concepts of permutations and combinations in an example that I found while reading my textbook.

Basically, it wants the number of elements in the set, *S*, of all lists *L* of length *n* that satisfy a given property.  Each element of the list is selected from a finite alphabet of size *q*.

The first part asks for the number of elements, given *L* has the property of having no repeated elements.  This seemed fairly simple and to be a straight combination problem.  Thus, I think the number of elements in *S* are $$\binom{q}{n},or~\frac{q!}{(q-n)!n!}$$

The next three parts are what I am having trouble with.

1. *L* contains no consecutive repeats, though farther repeats are ok.
2. *L* reads the same in both directions
3. *L* uses only three of the symbols in the *q*-symbol alphabet, one of which appears precisely 4 times in *L*, and another of which appears precisely 5 times in *L*.  Assume that *n* > 9.

It sounds like number 1. would be a mix of permutations (for the repeated numbers) and then combinations, due to order not mattering for the rest.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For 1., ask yourself how many ways there are of selecting the 1st element in the list. Now how many ways of selecting the 2nd element given that it should not be the same as the first. Now how many ways of selecting the third?

For 2., since $L$ reads the same backwards and forwards, after you choose the first elements you have no choice about the last element. After you choose the 2nd element, you have no choice about the last-but-one element. How far does this go? What if $n$ is even? What if $n$ odd?

For 3., be careful about cases like $xyxyxyxyzzzzz$ where two of the three symbols appear $4$ times and the other $5$ times.

Comment: Just to make sure I went after this the correct way, I believe the number of elements in the set **S** that do not have repeats would be $$q\cdot (q-1)^{n-1}$$.

Comment: Figured them all out, thanks for guidance!  It was the perfect amount of help.